# creating cpp files with a python script

Tags: python

For academic reasons, I want to write a python script that will auto-generate some c++ code by script that I write creating a cpp file and writing to that file. However when I try to run something like this

```
path = (wherever I want a cpp file to be created)
f = open(path, "w")
```

I get an error like this

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

I checked it out, and the problem seems to be that python can't find a file at the given path, and starts complaining instead of creating a new file and working on the created one. So how do I go about using python to create files other then text files

Comment: You need to ensure that `path` exists and specify a filename.

Comment: Aren't C++ code text files?

Comment: I want my program to auto-generate that file, not me create that file and then tell the program where to work

Comment: Your path is probably invalid, but since you haven't shown what it is, we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

`open` won't create a new directory, just a new file in an existing directory.  So if the directory `/path/to/directory/` exists, then

```
open('/path/to/directory/new_file.cpp','w')
```

will work.  However, if `/path/to/new_directory/` does not yet exist, then

```
open('/path/to/new_directory/new_file.cpp','w')
```

will raise `FileNotFoundError`

EDIT: additional information provided.

To create a path on the fly you can use:

```
import os
path = '/path/to/new_directory/'
file_name = 'filename.cpp'
os.makedirs(path)
f = open(path+file_name, 'w')
```

Comment: in my case most of the directory is already there. so it's more like open('/path/to/new_directory/', 'w'). I just want to have open create a new file there

Comment: I need to figure out what you mean by "most of"?  1. Does "/path/" exist?  2. Does "/path/to/" exist?  3. Does "/path/to/new_directory/" exist?  Clearly this is an analogy, the actual path would be more useful if you could provide it.

Comment: the path I want my script to use "C://Users/dasch/Documents/work/computer_science/C++/Data Structures/project/project/(file created by script)". the actual path is everything up until the second project tag

Comment: So "C://Users/dasch/Documents/work/computer_science/C++/Data Structures/project/" exists, but "C://Users/dasch/Documents/work/computer_science/C++/Data Structures/project/project/" does not, correct?

Comment: "C://Users/dasch/Documents/work/computer_science/C++/Data Structures/project/project" exits.